# im confused how functions work in python when im trying to use them

Tags: python

so the code is

```
magician_names = ['Elon musk', 'Neuralink', 'Neuralink']

def show_magicians(names):
    print("each object/person in the list:\n")
    for name in names:
        print(name.title())

def make_great(list):
    for q in list:
        q = 'the Great ' + q.title()


make_great(magician_names)
print(magician_names)
```

Comment: What part do you have troubles with?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: when I print(magician_names) I should get output of the great between each item in the list

Answer (score 0):

You are just reassigning the loop variable `q`, not actually mutating the list:

```
def make_great(list):
    for q in list:
        q = 'the Great ' + q.title()  
        # q is now a different new str object, but list is unchanged
```

do instead:

```
def make_great(lst):  # also do not shadow the built-in list
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i] = 'the Great ' + lst[i].title()
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is also right, you are not mutating list I ll try to clarify some things
let us see what is happening see the comment

```
magician_names = ['Elon musk', 'Neuralink', 'Neuralink'] #declared a list

def show_magicians(names): #defined a function though never called
    print("each object/person in the list:\n")
    for name in names:
        print(name.title())

def make_great(list): # defined a function
    for q in list: #iterated on list
        q = 'the Great ' + q.title() # stored a result into memory never used or printed it or returned anything


make_great(magician_names) #called the function operated on list never printed it but it worked in memory
print(magician_names)
```

In simple words if you have Dog Maxi(suppose a function) in a room  unless you **call** Maxi it wont come to you. But Maxi will stay in room *show_magicians* here. You called the Maxi and told him to say woof woof silently so you never heard him but Maxi said and did his job (like no print statement here).

Tried putting in real world analogy hope that helps